# "in case" vs. "if"

Tags: word-choice

> 1. “There are open fields over there,” he said, pointing, “***in case*** it happens.”
> 2. “There are open fields over there,” he said, pointing, “***if*** it happens.”

Are "if" and "in case" generally interchangeable? If not, how is 1, the original version, different from 2?

Comment: Use `if` for only one or two choices, use `case` statements when there are a bunch of them . . . ooops, I'm not in SO.  :-)  More seriously, there are times when one 'fits' better than the other - similarly to if vs case in programming - but generally, you can substitute one in for the other without altering the surrounding text too much.

Answer (score 3):

I read [it](http://novaenglishcampus.blogspot.in/2011/04/difference-between-if-and-in-case.html) a few months ago. Quoted from [the source](http://novaenglishcampus.blogspot.in/2011/04/difference-between-if-and-in-case.html).

> 1. I will buy some meat IF Jane comes.
> 2. I will buy some meat IN CASE Jane comes.
>
> According to the first sentence, I will buy meat only after Jane’s
> coming. In other words, Jane will come first then I will buy meat
> (otherwise I will not buy).
>
> The second sentence means, I will buy meat before Jane’s coming. It
> means, I am going to buy some meat first as I expect Jane but it does
> not matter whether Jane will come or not later.

Comment: In your example, *if* means *if and only if*.  In the OP's example, *if* is unlikely to have this meaning because the existence of "open fields over there" is unlikely to be contingent on whether they're needed by a particular person, so we instead interpret *if* as meaning *in case*.

Comment: @snailplane It was an answer to *Are "if" and "in case" generally interchangeable?*.

Comment: Since you didn't state the answer explicitly, I was afraid someone might read it and come to the conclusion that they're generally not interchangeable, which is false.  Hence, my comment.

Answer (score 1):

They are generally interchangeable. There are shades of meaning to them, but the difference is minor:

> “There are open fields over there,” he said, pointing, “in case it happens.”

Without further context, this seems to imply that whatever the event is that may happen, it is planned for. The field is there specifically for the situation at hand.

> “There are open fields over there,” he said, pointing, “if it happens.”

This has more of a "whatever happens is going to happen" feel to it. The field is there. It does not exist for the purpose of reacting to the event, but it can be used to handle the event.

Comment: If I read "in case of fire […]," I don't understand it to mean a fire is planned; I would understand it to mean there is a possibility it happens, even if I will never be there to see it happen.

Comment: You're right. But "In case of fire" is planning for the fire, even if it never happens. One installs fire hoses, fire extinguishers, and fire alarms for the express purposes of dealing with a fire. Nobody (aside from disturbed or criminal people) wants a fire to happen, but we plan for it regardless. On the other hand, "the kitchen sink is there, if the pot on the stove catches on fire."